# Single Sign Out with ADFS and STS

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0

We currently have problems with Single Sign Out with ADFS 2.0 and an external IP-STS. Our setup is that:
  RP1 <-- trust --> ADFS 2.0 <-- trust --> Custom IP-STS
  RP2 <-- trust --> ADFS 2.0 <-- trust --> Custom IP-STS

The Single Sign On part works very well that if users have already logged on using Custom IP-STS to access RP1, thereafter they can access RP2 in the same browser session without having to log on again.

However problem comes in sign out process. When users sign out from RP1, by using Fiddler we can see that:

1. Sign out request (wsignout1.0) is sent to ADFS
2. ADFS transfers sign out request to Custom IP-STS
3. Custom IP-STS processes sign out action properly, and then returns back to ADFS
4. ADFS does return back to (signed out) RP1
5. RP1 is no longer authenticated, so of course is prompted for logging in again (CORRECT)
6. HERE IS PROBLEM:   **RP2 is still able to work without any problem (with previous claim set). And ADFS does not send any wsignoutcleanup1.0 action to RP2.**

**I assume that ADFS should do sign out for all RPs having the same session, but it doesn't. Am I wrong? Or am I missing some kind of configuration here?**

Of course we have option to explicitly send wsignoutcleanup1.0 action to RPs from Custom IP-STS, but we need to parse the "wctx" in order to get the original RP Url which I don't want to.
I also tried to send wsignoutcleanup1.0 action back to ADFS from Custom IP-STS (step 3), but it didn't help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not returning iframes with wsignoutcleanup but rather images. Thus, adfs does not return **nested** iframes, in other words it doesn't escalate signout properly.

A correct sequence is

1 application sends the signout request to adfs

2 adfs escalates the request to the external sts

3 sts returns sequence of iframes pointing to authenticated applications (adfs in this case) with wsignoutcleanup

4 adfs returns a nested iframe with wsignoutcleanup to all authenticated apps, including rp1 and rp2

Comment: I don't use images as proposed in your sample in blogspot. My custom STS simply redirects back to ADFS (https://<domain>/adfs/ls/?requestContextId=....) when processing sign out, because it is the code from WCF STS Web Service template `FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignOutRequest(requestMessage, User, requestMessage.Reply, Response);`. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem. Follow my tutorial but render iframes instead of imgs. http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/wif-ws-federation-and-single-sign-out.html

Comment: It works now after stop passing `requestMessage.Reply` to `ProcessSignOutRequest`, and rendering iframe to ADFS with wsignoutcleanup action.

Comment: One more question: why it didn't work when I explicitly added wsignoutcleanup action to `requestMessage.Reply` before passing it to `ProcessSignOutRequest`?

Comment: Difficult to say with no http debugging trace. Use Fiddler or HttpFox to sniff all requests and responses and compare a valid sequence to an invalid one.

Comment: I have found out that ADFS actually does redirect back to the RP (where signout request comes from), and hence same redirection problem as above.

Comment: I have played around with these SSO based on your sample. It does help me a lot and things seem to be working fine so far. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the custom STS is not sending the signoutcleanup to ADFS.

Comment: Actually, I did while trying to find a solution. But as mentioned above, it didn't help. The sign out process still stops at ADFS.